# passing variable value between multiple subroutines

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Subroutine "Days" which has a variable Days. I want to pass values form that Days variable to a different subroutine "GetDays"

For eg:

Sub Day()
Dim Days() as variant
Days = Array(1,3,5,7,10,11)
End Sub

Sub GetDay()
'How do I get the values of Days here?
End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure I understand what you're after, but my best guess is that you want to set up a "DayClass" object that both holds the days values and returns them to other functions when they're needed:

(1) in the VBA editor, insert a **CLASS** module

(2) in the properties window for this module, change the name to (say) **DayClass**  (overriding the default name "Class1".)

(3) put this code into the DayClass module:

```
Private mDays As Variant  ' member variable to hold the days array

' initialization method to populate the array
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    mDays = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 11)
End Sub

' little function to return a particular value from the array
Public Property Get Day(i As Long)
    Day = mDays(i)
End Property
```

(4) To see the code above in action, insert a regular MODULE and put this little function in it, which may be invoked from the formula bar (if you want):

```
Public Function GetDays(i As Long)
    Dim DC As New DayClass  ' DC is dim'd of type DayClass
                            ' so via DC you can get at whatever is in there
    GetDays = DC.Day(i)     ' this function returns the i'th value of the 
                            ' array in DayClass, via DayClass's "Get Day" property              
End Function
```

(5) Since "GetDays" is a public function in a regular code module, you can test this out by entering the following formula into any spreadsheet cell:

```
=GetDays(3)

cell result = 7
```

Comment: Thanks! this helps. However, the mDays array is not fixed and will be updated as per user input. I know its going to be of length 5, but the inputs are not known

Comment: There is no way of doing it without creating an object? like  having mDays array in a module instead of Class module and then calling it in a different module?

Comment: You can do this in modules too - and things would look much the same.  Loosely speaking, you can think of each regular code module as a "singleton class" that doesn't need to be instantiated prior to use (like a static class in C#), and any variable you place up top would work just like class member variables.  Then just make "Get Day" a function rather than a property and prior to using any value from mDays make sure it has been initialized first (e.g. test for empty and if so, call the initialization routine).